# Actualizar Después de Insertar

Tags: vue.js

Estoy realizando un proyecto con vue, se tienen que insertar registros nuevos y poder editar los viejos.
Los registros que se insertan deben de aparecer en el componente superior, pero estos no aparecen hasta que se refresca la página de forma manual.
Como se puede hacer que una vez insertado el nuevo registro, este sea visible en el componente sin tener que refrescar de forma manual.
Gracias.

Comment: ¿Que has intentado? ¿Con que te has atascado?

Comment: He intentado hacer unforceRerender(), un settimer después de realizar el insert, peró sigo si que se actualice la tabla de registros.

Comment: ¿Se insertan en la misma página?

Comment: Hola, la datatable esta en una página y la inserción esta en otra.